# Return {array of object} in web services

Tags: arrays, web-services, jboss, wsdl

I am new to web services with JBoss. I would like to know how to return array of object for a function in web service.

for example:

It is easier for String:

```
@webmethod
public String func_name() {return null; }
```

But I want to return an array of object, so that I can generate a wsdl file:

```
  @webmethod
    public Person[] func_name() {return null; }
```

An error appears whenever I use the above webmethod.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I had to add getters and setters in the custom class. In this case Person.